# How can I avoid a group mismatch in regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I want to use regex to detect and match the tokens in a simple compiler.
I have used these regex patterns to be able to recognize Identifiers and if/for:

```
IF_RE = r'[\s]if+?[\s|\(]'
FOR_RE = r'[\s]for+?[\s|\(]'
IDENTIFIER_RE = r'[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,30}'
MIXED_RE = r'([\s]if+?[\s|\(])|([\s]for+?[\s|\(])|([_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,30})'
```

But the problem with the regex patterns above is that it detect if and for an Identifier group rather than simple if/for.
My question is where is why does this happen and how can I generally avoid problems like this?

Comment: This pattern `[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,30}` will also match `if` and `for` You might exclude that using a negative lookahead, and match the word characters 1-30 to prevent matching an empty string. `\b(?!(?:if|for)\b)[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}` The patterns `for` and `if` might also be written as `(?<!\S)if\s*\(` and `(?<!\S)for\s*\(` if you want to match `(` preceded by optional whitespace chars.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks. It fixed it. I wasn't aware of negative lookaheads and their concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `IDENTIFIER_RE = r'[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,30}'` also matches `if` and `for`

You can exclude that using a negative lookahead excluding if and for followed by a word boundary.

```
IDENTIFIER_RE = r'\b(?!(?:if|for)\b)[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,30}'
```

---

The `IF_RE = r'[\s]if+?[\s|\(]'` and `FOR_RE = r'[\s]for+?[\s|\(]'` parts match a mandatory whitespace char before, and match either a whitespace char or `(` after it, which can also match just `if` or `for`

This part for example `f+?` repeats 1+ times matching an `f` char as least as possible, where I assume it should be a single f

What you might do in both cases is assert a whitespace boundary to the left using `(?<!\S)` and match 0+ whitespace followed by `(`

```
IF_RE = r'(?<!\S)if\s*\('
FOR_RE = r'(?<!\S)for\s*\('
```